# RAM Usage Exceeded Error - EOS transaction

Tags: eosio-code

I received this error since I had multiple transfers to other accounts, is there a workaround for this so that I can continue sending tokens out?

> "code":500,"message":"Internal Service
>   Error","error":{"code":3080001,"name":"ram_usage_exceeded","what":"Account
>   using more than allotted RAM usage"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to buy ram for account which you used to do transaction.
For how to buy ram have a look at this https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-system-buyram

Comment: is this the only way? What if I wait? will my RAM be refreshed or sth?

Comment: RAM will not refreshed automatically CPU and NET Bandwidth will refreshed automatically may be in 48 hour.If your RAM refreshed than you will lost all your contract data and states.

Comment: so practically if I want to send anything from my account now I have to buy RAM, how did I get RAM in the first place then?

Comment: can't understand can you please be more specific?

Comment: When my EOS account was created, I already had some RAM, I did not buy that RAM, do new accounts come with some free RAM or when we stake we get RAM as long as we stake, there should be a better mechanism for having RAM=being able to perform free transactions

Comment: When we create a neew account there is some ammount of ram already available but if we need more ram than we can buy it also based on your usage . For transaction it uses only cpu cycles and net bandwidth.

Comment: I sent EETH to few accounts and every time it used some RAM, so by transactions do you mean sending only EOS coins and not the tokens?

Comment: It is based on your contract. As you said you send EETH yo some account now try to send again it to account which you have already sent EETH and observe RAM usage.